# - (id) from Obj-C Lib in Swift?

Tags: ios, xmpp, swift, xmppframework

At first, I'm very very bad at Obj-C (don't like the syntax), but now with Swift I love iPhone developing :D

Here is my problem, I try to work with a Obj-C Library (xmppframework), but when I try to initialize the XMPPRoster the required Method isn't available...

#### Objective-C usage:

```
xmppRosterStorage = [[XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage alloc] initWithInMemoryStore];  
xmppRoster = [[XMPPRoster alloc] initWithRosterStorage:xmppRosterStorage];
```

But within my Swift Class the Method "initWithRosterStorage" isn't available :(

#### Swift:

```
var jabberRosterStorage: XMPPCoreDataStorage = XMPPCoreDataStorage()
var jabberRoster:XMPPRoster = XMPPRoster(....)
```

XMPPRoster.m:

```
- (id)initWithRosterStorage:(id <XMPPRosterStorage>)storage
{
    return [self initWithRosterStorage:storage dispatchQueue:NULL];
}
```

Maybe Swift has problem with (id) because in Swift I think it's now AnyObject

Comment: what error does `var jabberRoster:XMPPRoster = XMPPRoster(storage : jabberRosterStorage)` give you?

Answer (score 1):

Try initializing it like this in Swift:

```
var jabberRosterStorage: XMPPCoreDataStorage, XMPPRosterStorage = XMPPCoreDataStorage()

var jabberRoster: XMPPRoster = XMPPRoster(rosterStorage: jabberRosterStorage)
```

Swift will convert the `[[Class alloc] initWithVar:variable]` to `Class(var: variable)`.

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-XID_26)

Comment: I already tried that.. Error: Incorrect argument label in call (have 'rosterStorage:', expceted 'dispatchQueue')... but thats strange because in XMPPRoster.h it's defined as following

    - (id)initWithRosterStorage:(id <XMPPRosterStorage>)storage;
    - (id)initWithRosterStorage:(id <XMPPRosterStorage>)storage dispatchQueue:(dispatch_queue_t)queue;

Comment: I've updated my answer. Try casting `jabberRosterStorage` to the required protocol.

Comment: i also have the same problem, please help