# Accessing Obj-C Class initializer from Swift

Tags: ios, swift, initializer

I am struggling to access an Obj-C Class method from swift and I don't understand why / what is going on....

**Obj-C header file**

```
// Visible in swift
+ (Player *)methodInManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)moc
                           withGivenName:(NSString *)givenName
                              familyName:(NSString *)familyName;

// NOT Visible in swift
+ (Player *)newPlayerInManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)moc
                              withGivenName:(NSString *)givenName
                                 familyName:(NSString *)familyName
                                  otherName:(NSString *)otherNameOrNil
                                        sex:(NSString *)sexOrNil
                                dateOfBirth:(NSDate *)dateOfBirthOrNil
                            playingPosition:(NSString *)playingPositionOrNil
                                     rating:(NSNumber *)ratingOrNil
                                currentClub:(Club *)currentClubOrNil
                              previousClubs:(NSSet *)previousClubsOrNil
                                       team:(Team *)teamOrNil
                                      error:(NSError **)error;
```

**Swift file**

```
   let player1: Player = Player.methodInManagedObjectContext(moc, withGivenName: "Damien", familyName: "Laughton")

//   let player2: Player = Player.newPl
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072808/id-from-obj-c-lib-in-swift) SO question which methions initWith: being converted by swift but I cant find any methods in autocomplete which match my missing method signature ...

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: Have you tried just `givenName`? The `with` part will also be removed.